# Stop iframe capturing mouse input

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with a web application that is able to include other web pages or plugin-esque content via an html iframe. The HTML structure of this application looks approx. like this:

[image]

The problem with this is that the iframe captures the mouses input when I drag the resizing handle and I guess that the resizing logic (JS) can't update the right areas size.

What I want is essentially how jsbin handles the iframe (the html output in the right column is inside an iframe): jsbin.com

You can resize the ouput column and the mouse isn't grabbed my the iframe which would result in said "blocking".

Comment: Can you place a transparent element over the iframe when you mouse down? That way the mouse is actually over the new element, not the iframe

Comment: Maybe I could. Do you mean wrapping the iframe inside a div or actually having another div **above** the iframe?

Comment: Having one above (position: absolute) in the same element which contains the iframe

Answer (score 2):

jsbin has a draggable `div`, used for resizing, a container `div` which is resized, a transparent `div` with a `zIndex` of 9999 that stays over the `iframe` and that 's why it is not receiving mouse events.